# Matlab alphaShape double to single precision to prevent out of memory error

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I am creating a highly detail mesh with some crack to run a FEM simulation. I am using Matlab `ndgrid` to create the grid and after I calculate my crack. I am using single precision so the data fits in my memory. But `alphaShape` class attributes are double precision and I can not modified. Is there a way to set or change precision to use `alphaShape`?

If I use single precision points I got:

> Error using alphaShape
>   Input arguments to alphaShape for points, alpha value, and threshold values, if specified, must be full (nonsparse), real, and double. For Name-Value pairs, the Name should be a character vector.

Comment: Can you reduce the number of points further away from the crack?

Comment: I also tried that, but when I increase the complexity of the and number of cracks the reduction of the external points is minimum.